# How to set an OnClickListener on an ImageButton

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an ImageButton defined in my XML and I'm trying to set an OnClickListener in my Java code. But when I click on it nothing happens as if it's not clickable... Can anybody help me, please?

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/facebook_link"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon" />
```

```java
ImageButton facebook=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_link);
final WebView webview=new WebView(this);
facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
        setContentView(webview);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this,

```
public class YourWebViewActivity extends Activity {

private ImageButton mFacebook;
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance);
  setContentView(R.layout.web_view_layout);

 mFacebook=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_link);
 mWebView=new WebView(this);
 mFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
        setContentView(mWebView);

    }
}); 
}
}
```

In web_view_layout.xml, Apply this

```
  <ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/facebook_link"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Bro Thanks i tried it when i launch my app still nothing happens as if iam not touching it :s

Comment: i already did that cause iam retrieving data from the internet

Comment: Take a look at this, example    http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: The problem is not in the code i think cause i tried it in my project in another activity it worked perfectly and the same way u people suggested but i got an activity called contact_us iam applying the same method i'm getting nothing its frustrating.Thank you guys